# How to subtract user inputted value in a specific table value?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

For Example lets say I have a table created name 'Budget' and column 'funds'.  when a user inputted a value in a VB form, it will save in registration table in the 'amount' column and the value inputted in that will be deducted in the 'funds'. I tried this but failed.

```
Update 'Table Name' SET Funds = (Funds - 'Value inserted')
```

Comment: If Funds is a numeric type (as it should be) how do you think that subtracting a string from a number would work?

Answer (score 1):

it is the correct query might be the data type of inserted value differ with funds.

```
Update 'Table Name' SET Funds = (Funds - 'Value inserted')
```